# workflow and Toolbox

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I have Toolbox for Activity where I have Activities listed and on right side I have designer where Workflow designer is placed. From my Toolbox I can drag and drop Activites into designer It works fine. Now to increase the usability experience I want to double click on Activity in toolbox and it should be added automatically into desinger as the last activity in sequence workflow ? How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you are self hosting the workflow designer here. The worklfow designer does so by default in VS2010 and as the rehosted designer is the same thing I would expect the same behavior here, not really sure if it does though. If it doesn't you can do whatever you like, and that includes adding activities to the design surface, in code.